# Unwanted loop in code when printing stock chart

Tags: node.js, image, discord.js

I'm trying to get my discord bot to display charts from finviz based on timeframe, but for some reason, discord keeps printing the same chart over and over. Any ideas?

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const token = '...';
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = "!";
var timeVal;

client.on('message',msg=>{
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix+"d"))
        timeVal = "d";
    else if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix+"w"))
        timeVal = "w";
    else if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix+"m"))
        timeVal = "m";

    msg.channel.send("test",{
        files :
        [`https://finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=OMN&ty=c&ta=0&p=${timeVal}&s=l.png`]

    });

});





client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("Bot is connected");
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: hi, can you display the msg.content and your https url

Answer (score 1):

Your bot is listening to **all** messages, including it's own. Try wrapping the send message function inside a if statement, something like

```js
client.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return; // Ignores anything sent by a bot account
    if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        let replaced = msg.content.replace(prefix, ''); // This only occurs once.
        if (replaced.toLowerCase().startsWith('d'))
            timeVal = "d";
        else if (replaced.toLowerCase().startsWith('w'))
            timeVal = "w";
        else if (replaced.toLowerCase().startsWith('m'))
            timeVal = "m";

        if (timeVal) {
            msg.channel.send("test", {
                files: [`https://finviz.com/chart.ashx?t=OMN&ty=c&ta=0&p=${timeVal}&s=l.png`]

            });
            timeVal = '';
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is first check if it's being sent by a bot, and if so ignore it. Then, check if `timeVal` has been set, then try sending a message. After the message is sent, reset `timeVal` so it doesn't execute whenever the message starts with the prefix. This is to ensure it doesn't try sending again if anything after `!` in the message isn't d, w, or m.